# Number Format Using ExcelJS

Tags: excel, angular, exceljs, sheetjs

I am trying to apply number format using **ExcelJS** in Angular-6
For Example : +ive number should display same and -ive number should enclosed in small braces
Here is my code for doing this

```
worksheet.getCell('F10').numFmt = '#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)';
worksheet.getCell('F10').value = -28106.53;
```

Value is assigned to cell correctly but show hashes `#####` on protected mode like when I download the file from browser.
*After enabling edit:* On cell focus it display the value properly

Comment: Is the column wide enough to display the formatted values.

Comment: @AndyG bundle of thanks bro u are a savior

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with some format on cells and I used **{dateFormats:[]}**

```
readFile(filename, {dateFormats:[]})
```

That worked for me.